# Labeling in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, spatial-join

I have two datasets, the first is a polygon dataset of wellsite pads in NE British Columbia. The second is a point dataset representing well heads in the same area. The point dataset has an attribute describing the location of the well head, this is the attribute I want to use to label with.

The problem is, is that it is not a one to one relationship. One wellsite pad can have multiple wellheads on it and there is no attribute linking the two. What I want to do is label each well pad (polygon) with a list of stacked labels of well heads that are on that pad. See screenshot example of the kind of things I'm after.

[image]

---

I sketched up some examples in CAD to illustrate my problem. If I label the wellhead data I get something like the below sketch

[image]

How do I have the well head labels for each pad neatly ordered and stacked?

See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to link or join your two datasets?  If your points have the information, can't you just label those points?

Comment: The catch is I want the labels to grouped by the wellsite pad, i.e. a list for wellheads for each pad

Comment: So your wellheads points aren't on the wellpad polygon?  I'm not sure I understand the problem.   Or are they just labeling in the wrong place?

Comment: I'll edit my post to include more info

Comment: is all the info (pad sites) in the same table?

Comment: What about Feature linked Annotation?

Comment: @rockycove Is it correct to assume that the order of the labels in the stack is important? I. e. the top label should represent the top wellhead point?

Comment: Can you use [field mapping](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/using-the-field-mapping-control.htm) with the merge rule set to 'join' to join the points to the polygon and then label the polygon? Just make the separator a line break in the labeling language of your choice

Answer (score -2):

If all your data is located in the same table just create a label expression see below as example

`def FindLabel ([attribute1], [attribute2], [attribute3]):
    return [LEGACY_ID] + "\n" + [attribute2]  + "\n" + "[attribute3]`

Comment: I'm unsure how this would work?  My understanding is that the well head labels are from different features, not different attributes of the same feature.

Comment: The attribute data I need is in the point shp, but there is no common attribute between the point shp and the polygon shp

Comment: perform a join so all the data is in the polygon table then build your label expression for your appropriate fields https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151826/merging-polygon-and-point-shapefile-in-arcgis-for-desktop

Comment: just realized you said there is no common identifier between the two tables...apologize for mis-reading

Comment: Hey no probs, apologies on how badly I worded it